# Jenkins & AWS - Adding an existing stage from one build to another/ Call another build

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration, pipeline, aws-cdk

I currently have 2 pipelines in Jenkins. One is a full development build from Declarative: Checkout SCM through to Declarative: Post Actions with everything in between... build war, deploy to server and test etc.

I also have an AWS CDK pipeline that build's the backend/frontend and deploys.

Is there a way of adding the same deployment stage only from the AWS pipeline to the development pipeline? So I would basically have the development pipeline building with the dev deployment to server followed by the CDK deployment as part of same pipeline.

- Just as a follow up I don't mean add the extra stages/steps from the cdk build but for the develop build to trigger the cdk build once the develop build has success.

Answer (score 0):

Just a final update on this.

I just ended up adding the CDK stage in the Develop Build and using the CDK pipeline as a job with then triggers the upstream build.